# Python can't find where my txt file is, how can i link it or where do i need to put the file?

Tags: python

Python can't find where my .txt file is, how can I find the correct path to it or where do I need to put the file?

I tried the following but got an error:

```
with open("C:\Users\raynaud\Downloads\notlar.txt","r",encoding="utf-8") as file:

with open("dosya.txt","r",encoding= "utf-8") as file:
```

> `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dosya.txt'`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is `dosya.txt` in the same directory as your script? What does your folder structure look like?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python may give you some insight into why the first approach didn't work.

Comment: Is your file `dosya.txt` or `notlar.txt`?

Comment: i changed '\' to '/' and it worked thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using absolute path, you must place the file in the same directory as the script is. On absolute paths you should not use \ like `"C:\Users\UserName\"`, because \ is the escape character in Python (and many more languages). You must use it like this: `"C:\\Users\\UserName\\"`

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your current directory? It might be pointing to somewhere unexpected. Try:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```